# LinkedList.addAll fires null pointer exception in multithreaded application

Tags: java, multithreading, list, synchronization, lock-free

I have a LinkedList that is being modified by a single thread. But there are many threads reading it.

```
protected volatile LinkedList<V> list = new LinkedList<V>();
```

I need to retrieve this list at some point. So, when I do,

```
List<V> retList = new LinkedList<V>();
retList.addAll(list);
return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
```

I receive the following exception

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at java.util.LinkedList.toArray(LinkedList.java:866)
>       at java.util.LinkedList.addAll(LinkedList.java:269)
>       at java.util.LinkedList.addAll(LinkedList.java:247)

I have checked that the list or the values within it are not null. What is the correct approach when you have a single writer-multiple readers. The aim is **not** to have a synchronized list.

Comment: show where you are initializing list, which you are trying to add..possibly that's null...

Comment: @JayaramPradhan it is not null. I have checked it. It is initialized right during the definition.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. I don't believe that using `Collections.unmodifiableList` makes a view which is valid to use from multiple reading threads when you're modifying it from another thread...

Comment: @JonSkeet It is copying all the elements to a new list. Hence it is fine. if I had returned the original list with `Collections.unmodifiableList`, it would give me a `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: sorry, my bad. In just realised a silly mistake. Editing the question.

Comment: @user592748 no, it doesn't create a copy. It just wraps the original list into a proxy that throws an exceptiion when you call a mutating method.

Comment: @JBNizet in any case the error is at addAll. Would you know why NullPointerException

Comment: Probably because another thread is modifying it while addAll() is iteratring on it. You can't expect anything to work properly without synchronization.

Comment: Linked list is not a threadsafe construct, so even if you have a single writer, you still have the possibility of having some odd exceptions.  that looks like your base list was being modified while your target list was calling toArray on it resulting in an odd race condition that throws a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your volatile tag doesn't mean anything -- this has to do with the thread safety of the writable object.  If you do not want to implement proper memory barriers yourself, then you need to use a different class, like maybe:

Instead of:

```
protected volatile LinkedList<V> list = new LinkedList<V>();
```

Try using:

```
protected Deque<V> list = new [LinkedBlockingDeque][1]<V>();
```

I assume your using LinkedList instead of ArrayList because you want the Deque methods rather then the list methods.

If you really need list methods instead of dequeu methods, you can use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Anyway -- You need something that spits out a [weakly consistent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly) iterator rather then one of the standard java.util collections which all disclaim in their javadocs that they are not inherently thread-safe with any mix of readers and writers and are thus inappropriate for your use case without proper memory barriers.